Failed to precompile a developed package in Julia
I have been developing a pkg in my pc and it works just fine. However, when I clone the repository in another pc I cannot get my project to precompile.
I get the following error:
Failed to precompile XXXXXX [XXXXXXXX] to "C:\Users\XXXXX\.julia\compiled\v1.9\XXXXXX\jl_C24.tmp".
I activated the package environment and all but it does not work.

What is not being precompiled? What are you leaving out of the braces in your error message? I think we will need more details and an MRE to help you with your troubles.
